# Are some sites or features out of bounds for the WinRT WebView control?

Tags: webview, windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

If I create a new Metro project and add a WebView control only, then add this code:

```
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();

    wv1.Navigate(new Uri("http://www.amazon.com"));
}
```

I then get an `Unhandled Exception` (it gives me the option to debug with a new instance of VS).  If I try other websites, some work and some don't - I get a variety of errors, but `http://www.bbc.co.uk` for example works fine.  I assume this relates to specific features of the sites themselves.

Are there some website features that I can't access using the WebView control?  If so, is there a way around this?  I don't seem to be even able to catch the error (putting a try / catch around the above code does nothing).

Comment: Am I missing something here - 2 down votes and a close request - why?  This is a legitimate question.

Comment: Lots of overzealous people on the web... Here, get one more upvote to even it out.

Comment: I created a new project, added only a WebView and called wv1.Navigate(new Uri("http://www.amazon.com")); I did not get any exception and the Amazon home page loaded just fine. Can you give us more details about your error message?

Comment: I see nothing wrong with this question.  Perhaps you are testing your app behind a proxy that is filtering certain sites?

Comment: Then enabled, Javascript exception debugging will produce that kind of behavior for some sites. if you take VS on its offer of debugging exception you will see offending javascript code.

Comment: If that's so then how would I turn it off?

Comment: Amazon website is trying to use ActiveX controls: 
    var xhr=window.ActiveXObject?new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"):new XMLHttpRequest();
Which is not supported by WebView.